# Position img horizontal center, and hide overflow

Tags: html, css

I have an image of the size 133px X 320px (h X w)
and I want it to show in a box of height: 185px
so the Images get scaled up, but the width of the box is dynamic;

so how could I set up my img, to be centered in the box and not default aligned to the left.

current code

```
#container {
  width: 30%
}

.card-image {
  overflow:hidden;
  height: 185px;
  border: solid;
}
.card-image img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

or on [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/dhQL0P)

so i want to see the center of the placehold.it in the box, even if you resize the screen

using materializecss of they have an option that I'm not aware of :)

And if possible if the width get's bigger then the height, that the image get's the full width and overflow on top and bottom

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: You should provide some code, as said in the comment above at least show us what you have so far.

Comment: working on the fiddle :)

Answer (score 1):

easiest way is this: put your image as position absolute inside a relative container with following css attributes:

```
.containerParent {
    width: 185px;
    padding-bottom: 185px;
    height: 0;
}
```

and your image inside this div with:

```
.image {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: -500%;
    bottom: -500%;
    left: -500%;
    right: -500%;
    display: block;
}
```

and either fitWidth:

```
width: 100%
```

or fitHeight:

```
height: 100%;
```

there you go. centered images always scaled up to your parent container

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bn94yrj7/

Comment: added a fiddle, works with every image you want. without the use of  background images...

Comment: Im not even sure how your brain come up with this. Im so confused as too how you even wrote this code. This is not a good method, whatever it is you are trying to do because I'm pretty sure its nothing like what the OP has.

Answer (score -1):

Unless I am misunderstanding you, then you can use CSS and background-size: cover to achieve this affect

View example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/rrjpca5d/

```
.box {
    height: 133px;
    width: 320px;
   background: url(http://theludonarrative.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/2014-03-11_00010.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: the image is getting loaded via angular, so background is a bit harder to do and it isn't centered

Comment: Ah, I see. You could load the "background" property as an inline-style (Inline styles should generally be avoided, but in this case it would make sense)

Comment: True, but i would think this could be handeld by css, plnkr added if you wanna see the setup

Answer (score -1):

Fixed it:

```
#container {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 350px;
}

.card-image {
  height: 185px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid;
}

.card-image img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  bottom: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
  right: -9999px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I think @DomlThe-Bread deserves the answer and points as it was clearly his answer that lead you to the solution.

Comment: This is not a 'fix', but a terrible hack, it seems.